# How do I get a list of worker threads of nservicebus

Tags: nservicebus

How do I get a list of worker threads of nservicebus. I need to register workerThread ids in to db and then bind some type of messages to the exact workerthread. Real idea is handling poison messages. Want to block all the threads not to handle poison messages except specified ones. There will be a seperate service that will manage threads through database.

Comment: Sounds like a high tech solution. What is it that you're trying to acheive?

Comment: I have a queue and message handler on a 8 worker threads. Some messages with temporarily problems that cause too long timeouts, this delay appears in all 8 worker threads, so amount of messages in the queue start to increase. Solution is to drop some kind of messages to error queue before processing it. I can do it in all threads, but I want to keep some of them continue handling this poison messages to catch if the problem is solved to allow other threads to work with them.

Comment: What do you think about using the Circuit Breaker pattern in your handler?  You could base it on the size of the delay and shove those messages out of the way and retry later.

Comment: Adam Fyles, it won't help there is a lot of messages(10 mes/sec). Small delay will cause all of them to stack in the queue. and delay isn't always mean that message would not be handled.

Answer (score 1):

I would not try to do that. It is almost sure to run into problems.

Of course, in order to get some sort of "identity" for each thread, you could place something like this in your message handler:

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static readonly Guid ThreadId = Guid.NewGuid();
```

But again, *I wouldn't do that!* The guids would change every time the endpoint was restarted, for one.

You could also query the list of threads direct from .NET and try to determine which ones were the message handling threads, but that sounds so scary I don't even want to go into it.

**The real issue: Poison Message Handling**

As your comment states, the real problem is that a poison message is REALLY poison. Not only is it failing, but it's taking so long to do so that it's really screwing up all the other threads!

Since you are able to identify these messages based on certain properties of the message, I would detect and throw an exception before the operation that times out. All the time.

If you want to be able to test periodically to see if the issue has been fixed, you have a few options:

1. Test via other means, and return the messages to the source queue when it has been fixed.
2. Add an appSetting so that the quick-throw behavior is skipped when the config setting is enabled. Then periodically you can edit the config, restart the endpoint, see if it's fixed, and then switch it back if it isn't.
3. Create another message handler that maintains a thread-locked increment value of zero. Send it a control message to say "Hey, try one now." Then your quick-throw behavior can decrement that value and allow one through to see what happens. This is also dangerous of course. Make sure your locking is tight since you are now sharing this state between different message processing threads.

Comment: Thanks for solutions now I use the 2nd. I'm trying to use Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId; to identify thread in message handler, but wanted to know if I could get list of threadids before handling messages. If I find the answer I guess my solution would be the 4th one.